# Counting & Filling errors on Python grid

Tags: python

I'm making this program for a class and when it runs with this file the corner of the grid won't fully fill in:

[image]

I can't figure out where my problem is. My other problem is counting the number of "chambers" of color, the counter keeps giving numbers greater than the total number of squares. Here are the two functions that I'm having issues with. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
def fill(cave, row, col, color):
    """Fill a chamber of the cave with water, starting
    at row, col. Water can spread in all four cardinal
    directions, but cannot penetrate stone.  No effect
    if row or col are not inside the cave.

    Attempting to pour water where there is already WATER or STONE
    has no effect.  Attempting to pour water outside the cavern has
    no effect.  Attempting to pour water in a cell containing AIR 
    not only places colored water in that cell, but also spreads it
    in all directions by causing it to be poured in the cell to the 
    left and right and above and below. 

    Args: 
        cave: A matrix (list of lists) representing the cavern. Each 
            cell in the cave may hold AIR, STONE, or WATER.
        row: Starting row of the grid cell where we pour water
        col: Starting column of the grid cell where we pour water
        color: color of the water we try to pour in.
    """
    if cave[row][col] == AIR : 
        cave[row][col] = WATER
        if row > len(cave) or col > len(cave):
            grid.fill_cell(row, col, color)
            return  
        if row < 0 or col < 0:
            grid.fill_cell(row, col, color)
            return
        grid.fill_cell(row, col, color)
        fill(cave, row+1, col, color)
        fill(cave, row-1, col, color)
        fill(cave, row, col+1, color)
        fill(cave, row, col-1, color)

def main():
    """Reads a cave from a specified configuration file, 
    displays it, and fills each chamber with a different color
    of water.

    Args (from command line):
        Cave description file, example, "cave.txt"

    Usage: python3 cavern.py cave.txt
    """
    desc = sys.argv[1]
    cave = read_cave(desc)
    dump_cave(cave)  ## May be useful for debugging
    display(cave)
    chambers = 0
    for row in range( len(cave)) :
        for col in range( len(cave[0])):
            print("Testing row ", row, "col", col, " Found: ", cave[row][col])
            color = grid.get_cur_color()
            fill(cave, row, col, color)
            if cave[row][col] == STONE:
                chambers += 1           
                grid.get_next_color()
    print(chambers, " chambers in cavern")
    input("Press enter to close display")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what grid is, or what it's initialized to, but this really looks like a bounds problem:

```
if row > len(cave) or col > len(cave):
    grid.fill_cell(row, col, color)
    return  
if row < 0 or col < 0:
    grid.fill_cell(row, col, color)
    return
```

First off, you're filling the cell even if it's out of bounds?  Why?  Even if that doesn't throw some error, which apparently it's not, wouldn't that give you more squares than in your grid?

Also, okay, I can see a row or column less than 0 being out of the grid, but let's look at your len(cave)... I'm also going to assume that len(cave) is the number of cells along the side of a grid, since cave is a list of lists.  It'd map nicely.  So if len(cave) is 8, we have an 8 by 8 grid.  But you're using a 0 based two dimensional array.  So your max cell number should be len(cave)-1.

Fixing those two problems should remedy the situation.  But that aside, cool program.  Please add an update later showing what a working grid looks like :)

EDIT:
One more thing I see wrong.

```
if row > len(cave) or col > len(cave):
```

Needs to be:

```
if row > len(cave) or col > len(cave[0]):
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Honestly, I was just frustrated and added it in frustration and it filled in the yellow, blue and red squares that are touching the side of the window. So the entire rightmost cubes are empty still without the filling in the maximum bound test.



Changing the len(cave) to len(cave) - 1 also offsets the cubes and makes the colors random where the red and yellow are on the rightmost side again too.

Comment: Added one more suggestion.  Noticed your grid wasn't a square.